# Run each RSpec spec file individually

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have recently split the test bootstrapping process for a large repository into separate `spec_helper` and `rails_helper` files.

The specs currently pass when I run `rspec spec` but fail on Travis CI since it runs each spec file folded (in isolation):

```
rspec spec/foo/bar_spec.rb
rspec spec/foo/baz_spec.rb
# ...
```

What is a simple way to run each spec isolated and gather the failed specs? There are about 50 of them so I would rather not do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on MacOs/Linux, specs are in `./spec` and suffixed `_spec.rb`:

```
find spec -name '*_spec.rb' -exec bundle exec rspec {} \;
```

or

```
find spec -name '*_spec.rb' | xargs -I {} bundle exec rspec {}
```